# Many LEFT Joins (7) causing timeout - another way to do this or issue with code?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I'd like to be able to join a lot of tables together (9-10 or so), but even with only 7, it times out.  I tried indexing to the best of my knowledge (see attached EXPLAIN).  Are joins just not made to handle 7+ tables, or am I doing something wrong?

(As you can see in the EXPLAIN, there are VERY few records in the database.  Even if I can get this to work, what happens when there are 500,000+ records?

```
SELECT `Node`.`id`, `Node`.`name`, `Node`.`slug`, `Node`.`node_type_id`, `Node`.`site_id`, `Node`.`created`, `Node`.`modified`
FROM `mysite`.`nodes` AS `Node`
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_date_times` AS `DataDateTime` ON (`DataDateTime`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_locations` AS `DataLocation` ON (`DataLocation`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_media` AS `DataMedia` ON (`DataMedia`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_metas` AS `DataMeta` ON (`DataMeta`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_profiles` AS `DataProfile` ON (`DataProfile`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_products` AS `DataProduct` ON (`DataProduct`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_texts` AS `DataText` ON (`DataText`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY `Node`.`id`
```

[image: My EXPLAIN output]

I'm using JOINS because I want to be able to order the main results by it's joined tables, and be able to query against specific fields within each contain (potentially) - and I don't know of a good way to do that with separate queries.

Any thoughts/suggestions VERY welcome.

**Update:**

When run on a local copy of the database, it says that "copying to temp table" took 117 seconds, then does complete and shows all 7 records.

Comment: Lol. Your database crashes. (But more seriously, what does "crash" mean here?)

Comment: Define "crashing" - what happens? The server dies? The query returns an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: You are note selecting anything from the left joined tables. What's the point of having them there at all?

Comment: When using a 'GROUP BY' Clause, everything you select must either by an aggregate function, or be in the GROUP BY clause.  Otherwise you'll get an error.  But that error should have been in plaintext.

Comment: One thing is, wtf is that `WHERE 1=1`. That is an endless loop....That is why you are crashing

Comment: Corrected "it times out".  @zmbq - I will add further selects asap, but for now, I just want a working query - THEN I will add more to it.  Didn't seem a point to making it more complex when the simpler version isn't even working.

Comment: @icemanind - it's generated automatically by CakePHP (php framework), but doesn't appear to affect anything either way - it times out with or without it, and it's not a repeat loop - it's a WHERE clause.

Comment: START with the largest tables to the left, and `JOIN` to the right descending in table size.

Comment: @njk - we're talking about tables with between 1 and 20 rows.  I won't know during runtime which one of the data has more rows, but Nodes is the "main" data that all the other ones relate to.  But - with this few rows, I doubt that would be the cause (pls correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @Dave what is the data type for the columns you are joining on?

Comment: @icemanind, "1=1" means "true".  It's a great way of dynamically building SQL, where you can add on other clauses, each of which would have an "AND" at the beginning.

Comment: Maybe it times out because somebody else has the tables locked?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: That's not normally true in MySQL; see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: Since you apparently only want one record from each of those child-tables -- otherwise your `GROUP BY` wouldn't make sense -- maybe try changing some of those joins to subqueries?

Comment: @ruakh - Using subqueries would limit my options as far as ordering by one of the joined-tables fields, or adding conditions to the join tables that would limit the main results. (pls correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Dave: Using a subquery for *one* of the child-tables would not limit your options for ordering by *another* of the child-tables. I'm not suggesting that you convert *all* of the joins to subqueries, only that it's unlikely that you need *all* of them to be joins.

Comment: @Dave: Also, even if you did convert all of the joins to subqueries, you could still wrap your entire query in `SELECT ... FROM (entire_query_with_subqueries) t WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`. This may, or may not, perform better.

Comment: This is actually a lot of tables, I'm not sure how mysql is dealing (or not) in such situation, but I'd suggest do split the join into few steps, like: `CREATE TABLE step1 AS SELECT [join first two tables] ...; CREATE TABLE step2 AS SELECT [join step1 and third table] ...;` and so on.