# Data Structure causing impossible joins

Tags: mysql, performance, cakephp, database-design, left-join

**Tables:**

- nodes
- data_texts
- data_profiles
- data_locations
- data_profiles
- data_media
- data_products
- data_metas
- categories
- tags
- categories_nodes
- tags_nodes

This question is a generalized question and is on the back of another question

**Explanation:**

Each of the "data" tables has a `node_id` that refers back to the id of the nodes table (hasMany/belongsTo association).

A "Node" can be anything - a TV Show, a Movie, a Person, an Article...etc (all generated via a CMS, so the user can control what type of "Nodes" they want).

When pulling data, I want to be able to query against certain fields.  For example if they do a search, I want to be able to pull nodes that have `data_texts.title = '%george%'` or order by the datetime field in `data_locations`.

The problem is, when I do a join on all seven data tables (or more), the query has to hit so many combined rows that it just times out (even with a nearly empty database.... total 200 rows across the entire database).

I realize I can determine IF I need a join depending on what I'm doing - but even with five or six joins (once the database gets to 10k+ records), it's going to be horribly slow, if it works at all.  Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484702/many-left-joins-7-causing-timeout-another-way-to-do-this-or-issue-with-code), the query I'm using just doing a join on these tables times out completely.

Each node can have multiple rows of each data type (for multi-language reasons among others).

I'm completely defeated - I'm at the point where I think I need to restructure the entire thing, but don't have the time for that.  I've thought about combining all into one table, but aren't sure how....etc

---

**nodes**

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `slug` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `node_type_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `site_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `nodeTypeId` (`node_type_id`),
    INDEX `slug` (`slug`),
    INDEX `nodeId` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**data_texts:**

```
CREATE TABLE `data_texts` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subtitle` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `content` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `byline` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `language_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `foreign_key` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `model` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `node_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `nodeId` (`node_id`),
    INDEX `languageId_nodeId` (`language_id`, `node_id`),
    INDEX `foreignKey_model` (`foreign_key`, `model`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**data_profiles**

```
CREATE TABLE `data_profiles` (
`id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email_personal` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email_business` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email_other` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`description` LONGTEXT NULL,
`prefix` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_home` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_business` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_mobile` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_other` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`foreign_key` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`model` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`node_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`language_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`user_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `nodeId` (`node_id`),
INDEX `languageId_nodeId` (`node_id`, `language_id`),
INDEX `foreignKey_model` (`foreign_key`, `model`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**categories**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `node_type_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `site_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `slug` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `nodeTypeId` (`node_type_id`),
    INDEX `slug` (`slug`)
)
COMMENT='Used to categorize nodes'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**categories_nodes**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories_nodes` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `category_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `node_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `categoryId_nodeId` (`category_id`, `node_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**node_tags**

```
CREATE TABLE `node_tags` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `site_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `siteId` (`site_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**nodes_node_tags**

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes_node_tags` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `node_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `node_tag_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `node_id_node_tag_id` (`node_id`, `node_tag_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT `Node`.`id`, `Node`.`name`, `Node`.`slug`, `Node`.`node_type_id`, `Node`.`site_id`, `Node`.`created`, `Node`.`modified`
FROM `mysite`.`nodes` AS `Node`
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_date_times` AS `DataDateTime` ON (`DataDateTime`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_locations` AS `DataLocation` ON (`DataLocation`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_media` AS `DataMedia` ON (`DataMedia`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_metas` AS `DataMeta` ON (`DataMeta`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_profiles` AS `DataProfile` ON (`DataProfile`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_products` AS `DataProduct` ON (`DataProduct`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `mysite`.`data_texts` AS `DataText` ON (`DataText`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY `Node`.`id`
```

[image: EXPLAIN query]

Comment: Edit your question, and include the DDL for nodes, at least two or three of the "data_..." tables, and the last four tables.

Comment: **1)** How do you -querywise- join these tables? **2)** Why aren't you using relational structures with **InnoDB tables** (instead of MyISAM tables)?

Comment: @inhan - 1) Posted query and EXPLAIN 2) No idea - I don't know the difference

Comment: Try and find some fields you can restrict the `Node` table on. The `1=1` is bad, if you can first get the set of `Node` rows down via a filtering of some kind then it should ease the pressure on the `JOIN`s.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan - I literally have 7 rows in my 'nodes' table.  While I agree that in the future I need to limit it, right now, it's limited due to sheer lack of content.

Comment: Also, historically `MySQL` is terrible when it comes to joining more than 3-4 tables. You might need to consider denormalizing your design or possibly consider PostgreSQL which can handle more complicated queries ...

Comment: Try getting rid of the `GROUP BY` - I think thats causing the filesort and temporary table

Comment: @CodyCaughlan - because of the left joins, it's returning something like a million rows.  Removing the Group By, it still times out, it just times out without the end-goal of getting usable data :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16856/discussion-between-cody-caughlan-and-dave)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Secondly, remove the group by, see how well it runs then, and how many rows are involved. Shouldn't be that many, but it's interesting.

You don't need the 'nodeId' index on node (as you already have it as a primary key). Again, shouldn't make any difference.

The where clause is irrelevant. You can remove it with no effect one way or another.

Thirdly, well, something is seriously broken.

Have a quick look on how to start profiling (e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html) , and run a profile command to see where all the time is going. Post it here if it doesn't immediately show that something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfortunately not in a position where I can do any tests right now. I'll just throw out some ideas. I might be able to do some tests later.

- Be suspicious of different collations.
- Some of your ids are useless. For example, you should drop the column categories_nodes.id, and put a primary key constraint on {category_id, node_id} instead.
- Be suspicious of *any* design that requires joining all the tables at run time. There are better ways.
- Use innodb and foreign key constraints.

Comment: "Be suspicious of any design that requires joining all the tables at run time. There are better ways." - that's the point of my question I think - what ARE the better ways?

Comment: For starters, I'd try to create views to resolve the joins in each "anything"; one view for TV shows, one view for persons, etc.